# I intend to do classification modelling, but my target variable has only one value

Tags: classification, decision-trees, logistic-regression, missing-data

Currently I have a dataset and I am trying to predict whether someone will default on their bank loan.

The dataset is quite tricky. It covers those who have defaulted in the past, but is also tracking those with current loans. So we don’t know whether they will default in the future.

This means that the target variable (default, not default) has one unique value which is 1. There aren’t any observations that can describe the 0 class.

Assuming I can’t use external datasets, what’s the solution to this problem? How can I best understand those who have defaulted if I don’t have something to compare them to?

Answer (score 1):

> Assuming I can’t use external datasets, what’s the solution to this problem? How can I best understand those who have defaulted if I don’t have something to compare them to?

If you wanna use this only this data as **classification** task, you can't perform this task. You could way this around, by generated fake data with label 0(you think about which value of parameters comes to default).

But you could try **clustering** algorithms(like k-means) and find the groups of specific clients. Perhaps one of these groups its **group of default**.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [fuwiak's answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/71733/91594), you can cluster the *current loan* group, declare clusters to be classes, and see whether a good fraction from your *default* set gets classified in one of the classes/clusters. If yes, this class is predictive of *default*.

Another take would be to do anomaly detection: use you *default* set to train the detector and apply it on the *current loan* data set. The "anomalous" ones are those **not** likely to default.

Comment: Hi! you mentioned I should cluster the current loan group only? If I do that, how am I able to see whether the default set gets classified as one of a class/cluster? Can I not just perform k-means clustering on the entire dataset (current + defaulted)?

Comment: Clustering the entire data set can work, too. My approach only gives you some additional confidence: You cluster on one set and **validate** on the other.